# how to call a windows form's function from another windows form's event?

Tags: .net, forms

I am developing a windows based application in .net.

I have two forms. Form2 is instantiated and displayed when an event occurs in form1.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ...
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       .... 
    }
    public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
    {
      Form2.parent = this;

      Form2 f2 = new Form2();

      f2.show();
    }

}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    ...
    public static Form parent;
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       .... //want to call Form1's button1_Click() function.
    }

}
```

Now in Form2's button3_Click() function I want to call Form1's button1_Click() method.

I tried

```
parent.button1_Click(button3,null);
```

but this is not working.

please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare `parent` as being of type `Form1` rather than `Form`.

I would personally put it in the constructor though, rather than having it as a public static variable:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
    {
      Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);
      f2.show();
    }
}

...

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 parent;

    public Form2(Form1 parent)
    {
        this.parent = new parent;
    }
}
```